# How to code onclick function in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`homepage.html`:

```
<html>
<h2>Welcome To Employee Home Page !!!</h2>
<button type="button">Add Employee</button>
<button type="button">Delete Employee</button>
</html>
```

Here in my HTML page, I have two buttons namely Add Employee and Delete Employee. If I click on Add Employee button, it should redirect to a new page and same for the Delete Employee button. How can I do this in node.js? Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: NodeJs is a backend technology so your problem is to make a client script (working in js) that send a xhr to your node server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only browser and browser jsvm know about this events, nodejs it's server side JavaScript realization for collaborate with incoming requests and etc.